# デフォルト値を設定していないVARCHAR型カラムへ対して、デフォルト値を一括指定したい

Tags: mysql

**やりたいこと**
「サーバ: localhost」全体もしくは「指定データベース」を対象として、デフォルト値を設定していないVARCHAR型カラムを全て取得して、デフォルト値「''」を一括指定したい

**分からないこと**
デフォルト値を設定していないVARCHAR型カラムを、SELECTで抽出できますか？ どうやって？？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

次のクエリで抽出できると思います。

```sql
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_SCHEMA='DB名' and COLUMN_TYPE like 'varchar%' and COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL;
```

Comment: 期待した通り、抽出できました。

Comment: 「NULL」を除外して「デフォルト値を設定していないカラム」だけを取得することはできますか？　そもそも「COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL」と設定しているので、「デフォルト値を設定していないカラム」と「NULL」は同義なのですか？